# How to fix the java applet viewer window size

Tags: java, applet, window, size

I am creating a Java applet.

I can set the initial window size using `setSize(50,100)` method at `public void init(){}` but what I want to do is I want to fix the window size at a particular value such as `setSize(50,100)` where user can not resize the window. Is this possible?

the code where i want the fix window size feature is --

```
  public class appletForm extends Applet {

    /**
     * Initialization method that will be called after the applet is loaded
     * into the browser.
     */
     @Override
    public void init() {
        // TODO start asynchronous download of heavy resources
        setSize(500, 500);
        setResizable(false);//how to use this?
        setBackground(Color.yellow);
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics j){
        j.drawString("hellooooow",50,70);
    }
    // TODO overwrite start(), stop() and destroy() methods
 }
```

Comment: Please use backticks `like this` to represent code samples, not bold.

Answer (score 3):

```
setSize(500, 500);
```

That method should never be called in an applet.  The size of an applet should instead come from the HTML that loads it.  E.G.

```html
<applet code='appletForm' width=50 height=100></applet>
```

Comment: i used `setSize(500,500)` in applet viewer, and also want the predefined fixed  window in an applet viewer ! how to do that?

Comment: *"also want the predefined fixed window in an applet viewer "*  How many ways do you need me to say it?  H-T-M-L..

Comment: I am coding this in NetBeans, so want predefined window of applet viewer while the NetBeans showing the applet, not in HTML browser !!

Comment: If you're using the applet viewer to view it (which Netbeans uses by default, AFAIR) then there will be an HTML it uses to launch it.  Either way, you must stop this nonsense of setting the size in applet code.  It is not especially productive in development, and downright detrimental on deployment.  BTW - Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `isResizable` method to return `false` in your window; that way, it shouldn't be resized.

Comment: give the syntax of isResizable method and where to use,please !

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#isResizable() is the API documentation for it

Comment: may you please rewrite my code using `isResizable` method ?